# ServiceStack :How to get StatusCode from JsonServiceClient Get method

Tags: c#, servicestack, http-status-codes

I am calling ThirdParty API using `JsonServiceClient`.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(ServiceURL);
var response =  client.Get<Output>("Search?id=" + id);
```

Output is class represent response coming from Third party API. I am able to get output correctly. But I want to capture StatusCode of this API response. How can I do this?

Note I have tried WebHttpResponse object instead of Output(response class). But I want statuseCode should be property of Output class not parameter of 
`WebHttpResponse`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use a response filter, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(ServiceURL) {
    ResponseFilter = res => res.StatusCode.ToString().Print()
};
```

But ServiceStack Service Clients are only meant for consuming ServiceStack Services, for consuming 3rd party API's, I'd recommend using [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) instead, e.g:

```
var response = ServiceURL.CombineWith("Search").AddQueryParam("id",id)
    .GetJsonFromUrl(responseFilter:res => res.StatusCode)
    .FromJson<Output>();
```